# WPF/MVVM Wrap panel orientation

Tags: c#, css, wpf, mvvm

I'd like to display basically a matrix of buttons, the number of buttons change in runtime.
My problem is that I want them to be next to each other to fill up all the space I give them. I thought WrapPanel is the perfect way to do that but it puts the buttons under each other and I have no idea how to solve it.

```
    <Grid>
    <WrapPanel Width="250" Height="50" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="543,442,73,162"  >
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding States}"   >
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate  >
                    <Button Width="50" Height="25"  Content="{Binding StateName}" Padding="0"  ></Button>                   
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </WrapPanel>...</Grid>
```

States is a list of Items that contains a name and a ID number. If i want to add or remove buttons I modify the list. So the buttons appear but in vertical order and they go beyond the limits of the WrapPanel so if it is not big enough only some appears. They only use 50 width from the 250 and more then the 50 height. In this case if I put 5 buttons in it only shows 2 of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't wrap **`ItemsControl`** inside **`WrapPanel`**. Instead set it as **`ItemsPanel`** of ItemsControl.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding States}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Button Width="50" Height="25"  Content="{Binding StateName}"
                Padding="0"/>  
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <WrapPanel/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: And `UniformGrid` might be an alternative to `WrapPanel`.